# Infra red stretching frequency of carbon monoxide ligand in borane carbonyl compared to that of free carbon monoxide

Tags: coordination-compounds

Why is the infrared stretching frequency of $\ce{CO}$ in the borane carbonyl $\ce{BH3CO}$ more than that of free $\ce{CO}$?

Is there any real explanation for this?

There will be a small amount of hyperconjugation of $\ce{H}$ atoms from boron to carbon which would increase the electron density of carbon closer to boron due to which the $\ce{CO}$ bond strength should weaken.

Am I wrong anywhere or there is any other theory that explains this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the stretching frequency of CO in the adduct increases, hyperconjugation disfavours the experimental results because due to hyperconjugation, the CO bond weakens.Only Sigma donation to p orbital of B atom will increase the CO frequency in the adduct.